# How to test a url change with <Link /> react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library, testing-library

I want to test, when this 'Reset filters' button is clicked go to /offerings, but I don't know how to test this `<Link />` component from react-router-dom

**Button**

```
<Link to="/offerings">
   <StyledButton trackingId="reset-filters">Reset filters</StyledButton>
</Link>
```

**Test file:**

```
it('should go to /offerings when the button is clicked when logged in', () => {
    const wrapper = mountWithTheme(
      <Provider
        store={configureMockStore({
          user: {
            userState: {
              loggedIn: true,
            },
          },
        })}
      >
        <BrowserRouter>
          <MarketplaceEmptyState resetFilter={resetFilter} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    wrapper.find('MarketplaceEmptyState').setState({
      allStatusFetched: true,
    });

    expect(
      wrapper
        .find('[data-cy="empty-state-filter-copy"]')
        .first()
        .text()
    ).toEqual(`Please reset the filters.`);

    wrapper.find('button[id="reset-filters"]').simulate('click');

    const leftClick = {button: 0} << -----------------------------|
    userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/offerings/i), leftClick) << ------  Tried this but it's not working
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to test if you are actually navigating is, to add a second route with the path `/offerings` to the BrowserRouter in your test that renderers a TestComponent

After clicking the button check the screen if the TestComponent is rendered  then instead of the `MarketplaceEmptyState` (for example adding some text to the TestComponent and check if the text is there).